# Forex card for Australia

Tags: money, australia, payment-cards, exchange

I am traveling to Australia for vacation in end of December. I currently live in the United States on F1 visa(International Student). I am planning to buy a forex card for Australia currency. What is the best way for the people living US to get the forex card? The reason I wanted to get Forex card is that I have heard forex card is the cheapest option while buying something abroad. All other cards normally have some charge associated. Please suggest something in this regard.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...Forex Cards are really just pre-paid debit cards, like gift cards or even like electronic traveler's cheques.

You immigration status is not relevant by the way.

They are only 'cheaper' if you don't have an otherwise no-fee option available to you.  So, the first thing you should do is check your current credit or debit cards to see of there are foreign transaction fees involved.  If no, a Forex card doesn't get you that much other than the benefit of a not losing a primary card.

But, you may also loose any loss or purchase protection offered by you main cards.